# Call an awaitable method inside a Thread in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

In my C# 7.0 Code I like to use an old school Thread of type `Thread` to do some work. Inside this Thread, I need to use some async methods. What would be the best approach to call these methods?

Writing the thread function `async` does not make any sense.

```
this._networkListenerThread = new Thread(/* async here is not an option */() =>
{
    while (!this._listenerCancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try
        {
            //  This does not compile
            var packetBuffer = await this._commProxy.ReadAsync();

            doSomethingMore();
        }
    }
}
```

If we go down the call stack, finally there will be this call:

```
// _socket is of type Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothSocket
// .InputStream of type System.IO.Stream
// ReadAsync only returns when data arrived on the stream 
// or throws an exception when the connection is lost
var receivedBytes = await this._socket.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

For those wondering why I want to use a Thread instead of Task: I want to give it a meaningful name to enhance debugging. I did not find a way to name a Task. Besides of this, this Thread runs almost as long as the application runs, therefore a Thread does make sense for me.

Comment: Why not `Task.Run(() => SomeMethodName());` and `private async Task SomeMethodName`?

Comment: Does the `ReadAsync()` method return a Task? You can only `await` task objects. 
What compiler error do you get?

Comment: @Boregore Yes it returns `Task`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Cause I want to the Thread Name show up in my log files and in the Threads View of Visual Studio when I make Pause on the application.

Comment: If we are firing another thread what is the gain you will get to do the async inside that thread. As you are already off from your main thread which you do not want to block.

Comment: @this.myself you don't need a raw thread. You won't gain anything by awaiting for an already async operation inside yet another thread, you'll just waste the thread. *Why* do you think yo need a raw thread when you have a non-blocking call? And why use *Thread* instead of `Task.Run`?

Comment: What is the type of `_commProxy`? Is it an HttpClient, a WCF proxy, your own class? If it's your own class, what does `ReadAsync` do ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is my own class. And under it, my other own class. And under it, the Bluetooth Socket implementation of Xamarin.Forms on Android. Or the UWP Bluetooth Socket implementation. And ReadAsync() is blocking anyway until data was received or the socket is closed.

Comment: The point of asynchronous calls is to not block the thread and allow it to do other stuff.  But you've created your own raw thread that isn't going to go off an do other stuff so you might as well make a synchronous call instead.

Comment: @this.myself *why*? What blocks? If it does, *don't* return a task and don't name it `ReadAsync`. Post your code. At least, wrap the part that *blocks inside your class* with an `await Task.Run(...)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added some of the code of the lowest level. But it does not have to do anything with my question. I just like to know how to use an awaitable method in such a scenario.

Comment: _"I want to give it a meaningful name to enhance debugging."_ You are buying this at an overly high cost don't you think?

Comment: @this.myself it has *everything* to do with the question. `_socket.InputStream.ReadAsync` doesn't block. `await _socket.InputStream.ReadAsync` doesn't block, it *awaits* for the stream to return something and continues execution in the original context/thread/ You don't need *another* thread around it. Again though, if you want to run any operation in the background, just use `await Task.Run(()=> whatever())`. You don't need a raw thread

Comment: Go async all the way and be done with it. That's why you have ThreadPool with existing threads, so you don't have to pay for creating new ones.

Comment: @this.myself check the source code for [Stream.ReadAsync](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,e224b4bec8748849). It actually uses the *asynchronous* `BeginRead`, `EndRead` methods. It doesn't block

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "Not blocking" is not OP's concern. He wants the surrounding thread to have a constant thread name in the logs ... (a rather bad reason if you ask me)

Comment: @this.myself I think this is an XY-Question. What logging framework is in use?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know I do not need a raw thread, I could use Task.Run(). But I need to debug some large logs and try to make these logs more readable. By the way, I created a new question how to give a name to a Task, this would actually help me more.

Comment: @Fildor No logging framework and a lot of logging break points, which would print the name of the current thread when use $TNAME

Comment: @this.myself Yes, use `Task.Id` to give task identifier and use it in logs. I've deleted my answer as it's not relevant to updated question.

Comment: @this.myself I just noticed something interesting in Xamarin's docs for [InputStream](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Java.Net.Socket.InputStream/)  `If the socket has an associated SocketChannel and that channel is in non-blocking mode then reads from the stream will throw a IllegalBlockingModeException.` Searching for `xamarin bluetooth readasync` returns a lot of results that disucss blocking vs non-blocking acces even for *Read*, buffering etc.

Comment: [This article](https://brianpeek.com/connect-to-a-bluetooth-device-with-xamarinandroid/) shows that you should be able to simply use ConnectAsync then ReadAsync. Can you do that? Does it your in a bare-bones application? How do you know it *blocks* anyway?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for searching so wide. Searching for Bluetooth with Android shows a lot of hits with problems and just a few answers anyway... Unfortunatly, nothing is simple here, even if it seems so. On `await ReadAsync(buffer, offset, length)` the function will continue when it received some bytes from the stream or when ReadAsync throws an Java.IO.IOException (means socket closed).

Answer (score 2):

> this Thread runs almost as long as the application runs

No, it doesn't.  Because the work that it's doing is asynchronous.  The thread runs long enough to check the status of the cancellation token, fire off `ReadAsync` (which, being asynchronous, will return basically immediately) and then it's done.  The thread goes away, and it has no more work to do.  That's the whole idea of asynchronous operations; being asynchronous means the operation returns to its caller pretty much immediately, and does whatever meaningful work it has to do *after* returning control back to the caller (in this case, since this is the top level method of the thread, returning control back means that the thread has finished executing and gets torn down).

So there just isn't much of any purpose in creating a new thread just to have it check a boolean value and *start* some operation that will go off and do work on its own.  It's not that you should use a *different* way of getting a new thread to do work (like using `Task.Run`), but rather you shouldn't use *any* means of getting a new thread to do work, because you don't have any long running CPU bound work to do.  The long running (non-CPU bound, by the look of it) work that you have *is already asynchronous*, so you can just call the method directly from whatever thread wants to start this work, and have it do it right in line.

If you simply want to have some value that you can share along an asynchronous operation's logical call context, there are of course tools that accomplish that, such as `AsyncLocal`.  Creating a new thread *wouldn't* accomplish that, because as you finish starting the asynchronous operation you have your thread is dead and gone, and the continuations will be running in some other thread anyway.

Comment: This is a question about Xamarin and Bluetooth sockets. It may well be that there are quirks. Googling for `xamarin bluetooth readasync` returns a lot of hits talking about blocking vs non-blocking calls, missing data, buffering etc

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The point remains that using a `Thread` changes nothing over using `Task.Run`, and they know how to ensure that the operation is properly asynchronous using `Task.Run`, so I don't see how that meaningfully changes the answer.

Comment: @Servye it does, if the stream implementation blocks even when `ReasAsync` is used. *Read* may not block if the channel is opened as non-blocking, it will simply return no data if no data are available. Right now we don't know how that Bluetooth socket was created and configured.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Even if the method is conditionally not asynchronous, you still can't write the code under the assumption that it's always synchronous, or you'll get bitten on those occasions where it does even a portion of its work asynchronously.

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time I see a serial port driver behave unexpectedly, eg because the driver vendor decided to get smart. Code running in the emulator may work well but misbehave on a real device. .NET's own SerialPort.Read returns only what's in the buffer without blocking.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My point is not that the method couldn't behave unexpectedly (I may well behave unexpectedly).  The point of the answer is that using a `Thread` here doesn't solve the problem at hand, and whether this method is well behaved or poorly behaved doesn't change that.  It may require the OP to do some work to work around the poor behavior of that method, but not by using a `Thread` as they're trying to do.  They'd do it by using `Task.Run`, as they've already said they know how to do (so I didn't bother explaining how to use it).

Comment: In this case, using Read and polling isn't a great option because it will draing the battery just polling. It all depends on the actual device that shows the unexpected behaviour (if it actually does). Is it a config error? Bad connection mode? Or perhaps the code should be wrapped in a Task just-in-case it blocks? You'd waste a thread on *some* devices but avoid blocking the app on others

Comment: which is the point I'm making in the question's comments for the last hour or two. The fact it's a mobile device makes a difference. You can't assume the Earth isn't flat in this case.

Comment: Besides, if Read is can be non-blocking, what would the equivalent behaviour of ReadAsync be? Shouldn't it return immediatelly if there are no data? Until the OP posts the code that creates the socket we can't know. Even then, I wouldn't trust the *emulator* to behave the same as an actual device. I *have* encountered USB serial drivers by FTDI that didn't raise the proper handshake events automatically. Took me 1 month to convince the vendor that no, it wasnt' the stupid coder, your device can't even run the MSDN samples

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You're correct that it's possible for a poor implementation of the method to possibly run sychronously, and if the method is documented as sometimes doing work synchronously you can't rely on it always running entirely synchronously.  But that's not the point of the answer, the point is that you can't rely on it always running entirely synchronously, which is the only situation in which the OP's attempted solution would be of any meaningful help.  Since that assumption *can't* be made, they can't use that solution.  That's all this answer is saying.

Comment: @Servy When you say there is no need to create an own Thread or Task, what would you do then? Fact is, further down on the call stack, calling `await this._socket.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)` will wait until something was received on the socket. When I call this without doing Task.Run() or similar, my UI thread will wait for something incoming on the socket which is very useless in my situation (actually the app cannot continue).

Comment: @this.myself That's a situation where `ReadAsync` *says* it's asynchronous, but it's not actually entirely (consistently) asynchronous, so you may be forced to use `Task.Run` to ensure that the synchronous operations that that method is doing are done in a thread pool thread, not your main thread.  It's unfortunate that you have to do it, but that's really your only real option for how to work around a problem in that method's implementation.